# R loop a spred over list

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

A Hey I have a massive dataset I'm trying to spread in R and I keep running out of memory so trying to break it up and to write an efficent piece of code to loop over the list example structure below. I know#this will be dead easy to someone who understands these functions and appreciate any suggestions.

```
rs <- split(r,1:3)
```

Then spread the lists as below, but do so efficiently as there may be a large number of lists

```
rs$'1' <- rs$'1' %>% spread(movieId, resids)
rs$'2' <- rs$'2' %>% spread(movieId, resids)
rs$'3' <- rs$'3' %>% spread(movieId, resids)
```

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: Its about 10 million rows and I guess that spread function is quite expensive

Comment: And resids has 7,198,397 distinct values

Comment: Can you add two things to the question? (i) `object.size(r)` and (ii) `length(unique(r$movieId))`?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong it's not `resid` but `movieId` that matters regarding the distinct values. (I will delete the comment above)

Comment: Only 9,651 of those!

Comment: object.size(r) 144002080 bytes

Comment: length(unique(r$movieId)) 10651

Answer (score 1):

Considering the comments above, I would say:

1. Your dataset is not too big. 144 MB is totally handable unless your computer is from 1997.
2. `spread()` tries to create a dataframe with 10.000 rows. I think this is the reason, you're running out of memory.

The resulting point is: what do you eventually want to do with your data. It's likely that you actually not want to do `spread()`, but something else really.